# How to pond concrete

Tags: concrete

I recently got interested in making pots out of cement. The most practical curing method for me is ponding/submergence. When is concrete ready to pond, how can I tell when it's ready, and what should I do with it in the mean time? And can/should I remove it from the mold before submerging? I'm using a normal, higher strength cement mix you could find at a hardware store if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the pour is set you can remove from the mold and submerge, I help a friend that has yard art molds he submerges some pieces, not all, for strength especially in the warmer weather. The molds release easier when the mix is set but still green or not fully cured leaving the form on longer makes it harder to clean.